# How do I localize a string that contains a date and the location of the text differs depending on the language?

Tags: swift, localization, nslocalizedstring, dateformatter

I'm localizing my app for Hungarian users and having trouble figuring out how to handle a string with a date in it.

In English, I have a text string that should say "4 reps @ 120 kg on 8/19/23". I'm having trouble with the "on 8/19/23" part of that because in Hungarian the "on" comes after the date like this "19. 08. 23.-én". Here's my code for localizing "on 8/19/23"

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMddyy")
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: viewData.liftDate)

let onDateText = NSLocalizedString("onDateText", 
                                    tableName: "Main", 
                                    value: formattedDate, <-- a string
                                    comment: "")

liftDate.text = onDateText
```

And in my localizable.strings file I have this:

```
"onDateText" = "%@-én";
```

And what's appearing in my app is "4 ismétlésszám @ 120.0 kg %@-én"

I need help understanding how to get the date included in the localized string that's returned.

Note: The screen this appears on is a UIViewController, not a SwiftUI view.

I've read lots of posts here on SO and have tried to figure it out using the commonly recommended [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1), but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the result of `NSLocalizedString` as a string format. The value you pass in is the default string format.

Your update code would look something like this:

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMddyy")
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: viewData.liftDate)

let onDateFormat = NSLocalizedString("onDateText",
                                    tableName: "Main",
                                    value: "on %@",
                                    comment: "")

liftDate.text = String(format: onDateFormat, formattedDate)
```

Note the change in the `value` parameter for `NSLocalizedString`. Also note the use of `String(format:)` to create the final string.

By having the base format string in `NSLocalizedString`, you can use the standard localization tools to generate the base Localizable.strings file from your code.

At runtime, the actual value returned by `NSLocalizedString` will be the actual localized value based on the user's locale.